# How can I use the onDisconnect method with PolymerFire?

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-realtime-database, polymerfire

Using the Firebase Javascript library, I can use the onDisconnect() method to schedule a database update when the client is disconnected.

Google has released a set of Polymer Elements called PolymerFire, which make hooking Polymer apps and Firebase very easy.

Has anybody figured out how to use the onDisconnect method from inside a Polymer app using PolymerFire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer!

So, at the start of my app, I initialized the firebase-app like this:

```
<firebase-app name="notes" ...></firebase-app>
```

Then, later in my app, I add a firebase-document to watch my connection status:

```
<firebase-document app-name="notes" path="/.info/connected" data={{conStatData}}>
</firebase-document>
```

and I added an observer on conStatData:

```
observers: ['_conStat(user, conStatData)'],
```

And finally, the payoff code:

```
_conStat: function(user, status) {
      if (status === true) {
          firebase.app('notes').database().ref('/presence/' + user.uid).set('online')
          firebase.app('notes').database().ref('/presence/' + user.uid).onDisconnect().set('offline')
      }
  },
```

Comment: I would add `user` to the observer parameters and use `user.uid` (instead of  `this.user.uid`) in case `user` is not yet defined (e.g., the user is not yet logged in).